# webbrowser.open in older versions' of python

Tags: python

Is there a way to make this program listed below work in older versions' of python?

```
import webbrowser
WebCho = input("Would you like to visit the samsung site to check if you still have a warranty left for your phone: yes / no ").lower()
while WebCho == 'yes' or WebCho == 'no':
        if WebCho == 'yes':
                webbrowser.open("http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/")
                break
        if WebCho == 'no':
                print ('Thanks you for visiting our trouble shooting program')
                break
```

Comment: What is your current version and which version you are looking for this to work?

Comment: The version is python 3/ 3.3 im not certain but when i try this program above it doesn't work on older versions of python and i wanted to find a solution that would work for older versions of python.

Comment: P.s Sorry for responding 12 hours later it was quite late, when i was awake.

Comment: and my current version is python 3.5

Comment: Can you provide the errors when you run this program on old Python versions?

Comment: I found a solution and i used other modules such as the OS one and it worked !.